# manual add all users from Users Awaiting Email Confirmation to Registered Users

Tags: vbulletin

My problem is all by user are ending in  "[B]Users Awaiting Email Confirmation[/B]"

I know users are not getting Confirmation email. so I want to manual add all users from 
Users Awaiting Email Confirmation to Registered Users

is there are way by which I can move all 1500+ users from Users Awaiting Email Confirmation to Registered Users

Not one by one

Regards

Answer (score 0):

If the usergroup IDs are the same as the default, then a simple:

```
UPDATE user SET usergroupid = 2 WHERE usergroupid = 3;
```

will do the job.